# Search within code block

Tags: bug, search

When I try to search the term '*ActivityNotFoundException*' SP SE returns 0 search results. But posts containing this term actually exist (e.g. ["The activity named 'WorkflowXaml_GUID' from scope was not found" when deploying SP 2013 Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118820/the-activity-named-workflowxaml-guid-from-scope-was-not-found-when-deploying)).

I am guessing it has something to do with indexing tokens inside `code block` because if I search for any other term in aforementioned post, I get search results.

Is it a possible bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search within code block only if you type `code:"search argument"` when the search argument is surrounded by spaces or `:`. But your specific case has the entire class written out which means that you need to search for `code:"Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException:"` which receives the result your interested in. Lose the code and you'll get three answers searching for the class `Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException`

Ref:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException%3A%22

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException

So it's a bad search implementetion if you ask me, which needs to be improved. Maybe you'd like to post this suggestion on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thank you for clarification. It is definitely a bad implementation because some users will post "Exception has occurred" while other users will post "System.Exception has occurred". So in order to properly search through SE you always need to search for both variants.

Comment: @SlavenSemper for our future reference, note that [Google finds those posts just fine](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Asharepoint.stackexchange.com%20activitynotfoundexception) - we're looking at search now, so maybe we can tweak this, too.

Comment: @JarrodDixon That's great news! I hope you make search awesome :-)